# JQuery not being run in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, conditional-comments

I'm having an issue with a site I'm building.

One feature of the site is a survey which asks for information.  One type of question is a 'Visual Choice Question' that shows images that can be clicked.  These images correspond to (hidden) checkboxes, which record their answers.  A checked item is given a border, which results in a nice visual experience for our users.

Those users in IE8, however, can't click images - `<img>` tags within labels aren't clickable in IE8, and the `:checked` CSS selector isn't usable.  Our stakeholders are fine with IE8 having a degraded experience, but it has to work for them.

In order for IE8's experience to degrade gracefully, I wrapped the survey in an IE8-only div (using Conditional Comments so that only IE8 and below would get it) and wrote a line or two of CSS so that the checkboxes would be visible.

Unfortunately, the checkboxes are outside of a floating element, and thus render very far from where the element is.

I wrote some jQuery that would detach the checkboxes and re-attach them within the floating elements.  I wrapped this jQuery in the same sort of conditional comments, tested it in IE11's Developer Toolbar-enabled IE8 mode, and pushed the code to the server.

It fails on real IE8.  The code, including the jQuery which is wrapped in conditional comments, works on IE11's emulated IE8 but not on real IE8.

What can I do to resolve this?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5QGU/) which shows a simplified version of a survey question.  The code in the javascript panel is wrapped in `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` tags on the final page.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating the solution with using all these conditional hacks.

All you need to do is address the one issue you're facing with IE8, it doesn't support the clicking of labels.

You can do this simply by binding the click event of the labels directly to the inputs themselves.

This should work for your needs (include it somewhere after jQuery is loaded).

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("label").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("for") != "")
            $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).click();
    });
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure the `for=""` on your labels matches the `id=""` on your inputs.

Comment: This doesn't fully fix the issue.  The reason I've had to resort to these hacks is because IE8 also doesn't support the CSS techniques I'm using to put a border around the selected answers.  Lacking checkbox and border, there is no way for the user to know if their click did anything.

Comment: Then write a simple jQuery script that applies a class to the element based on the checkbox being selected, then style that class to show a border.  Using conditional hacks should be used as a last resort.